# How do I create an apk file from kivy with github

Tags: python, android, kivy, github-actions, buildozer

Is there a way to convert a kivy file to apk on github. I have been looking around online and there seems to be possible but I am not sure how to do it. If someone could help me I would be very thankfull because I cannot find a way to convert my kivy file to apk. I have tried bulldozer on a vm and rpi but keep getting errors

Comment: python-for-android has Github Actions workflow definitions for building apks, in that case for testing purposes. These should show how to do it. I think there are other examples people have made too.

Comment: Also since you mention rpi: this is not a supported build platform, you probably can't get it to work there.

Comment: you can use gitlab .i did it work for my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

main.yml

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 1,15 * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # used to cache dependencies with a timeout
      - name: Get Date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
        shell: bash

      - name: Cache Buildozer global directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer_global
          key: buildozer-global-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }} # Replace with your path

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.get-date.outputs.date }}-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - name: Build with Buildozer
        uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
        id: buildozer
        with:
          command: buildozer android debug
          buildozer_version: master

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```

Step 1: make a repo in GitHub.

Step 2: Add all your project files to the repo

(Make sure your main.py and buildozer.spec are in the root dir   i.e.: out side of any-folders)

Step 3 : Go to Github action and there will be an option to setup yourself, when you click on it paste the code above and save changes.

(When you edit the main.yml file and save ,it will start a build, in the .yml file you can see it has been given to build when there is a push into repo or merge into the repo.)

Step 4: You have made the CI pipeline , now you will have to wait for it to build. You can see the logs in Realtime  in the pipelines.

For an working example refer to this repo:
[Github repo](https://github.com/tshirtman/p4a_lottie_demo)