# Android Buildozer failed

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I wanted to compile a kivy-app (I managed to do this before). I made sure, there is no spacing in file names or such, since I have read, that this may be the reason for the problem.

After I got an error, I tried to build it with the default buildozer.spec - still the same error.

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1294, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 728, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in wrapper_func
    user_ndk_api=self.ndk_api)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 423, in prepare_build_environment
    self.ccache = sh.which("ccache")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 1524, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 788, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/which ccache

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = '104712d8a60f'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '43'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220712'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
    

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 
    
      RAN: /usr/bin/which ccache
    
      STDOUT:
    
    
      STDERR:
    
    # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=scrabbleapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
    #     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
    #     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
    #     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
    #     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    #     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
    #     HOSTNAME = '4defd10a4368'
    #     OLDPWD = '/'
    #     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
    #     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
    #     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
    #     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
    #     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
    #     PAGER = 'cat'
    #     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
    #     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
    #     JPY_PARENT_PID = '41'
    #     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
    #     PWD = '/content'
    #     HOME = '/root'
    #     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220712'
    #     CLICOLOR = '1'
    #     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
    #     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
    #     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
    #     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
    #     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-color'
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
    #     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
    #     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
    #     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
    #     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
    #     SHLVL = '1'
    #     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
    #     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
     'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
    #     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
    #     COLAB_GPU = '0'
    #     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
    #     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
    #     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
    #     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
    #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
    #     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    #     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
    #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

The buildozer.spec I used first is this:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Scrabble

# (str) Package name
package.name = scrabbleapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = 

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version = 0.35

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/loadingscreen.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename =  %(source.dir)s/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class instead of PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk).
# android.release_artifact = aab

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = develop

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I would be very happy for help.

Comment: I just found out, it is a problem with Google Colab. This helps (found it somewhere else): 
uncomment p4a.branch = master in the buildozer spec file and change the "master" to "develop"

Answer (score 0):

At around line 300 in the `buildozer.spec` file you will find `python-for-android branch`. There is currently an issue, and because of this you must change the `p4a branch` to `develop`.

```
# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = develop
```

If even after changing this your app failes to build, then you should try downgrading the `cython` version in `Google Colab`.

You could also use the [GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761765/how-do-i-create-an-apk-file-from-kivy-with-github) way to build an `apk` with `buildozer`.